# How to use of pay pal java API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am developing web application in that i have included pay pal payment system, i am making use of java API my, i have got API key, password and API certificates also, but i dont no where to use that, i have gone through the documentation which is in pay pal but didn't get solutions please help me out.
i have downloaded samples from the below links:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks

Answer (score 7):

[Here](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-java/blob/master/README.md) you can get some guidance:

- Copy 'adaptivepayments-java-sdk.jar' to your class path.
- Copy the configuration file 'sdk_config.properties' in SDK 'resource' folder to your project.
- Import `AdaptivePaymentsService` into your code.
- Load the configuration file into your application with this method call as required:

  ```
  new AdaptivePaymentsService(new File(".../sdk_config.properties"));
  ```
- Create a service wrapper object.
- Create a request object as per your project needs.
- Invoke the appropriate method on the service wrapper object.