# Android : How to sale some image on android application (Coding)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I created an android app to display a lot of images some of them are free, but for the rest I want users buy them, how can I sell those images?
What code should I add to let users buy images using android market.

Comment: First Google something, try something and you can come shouting to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Paypal` is a good option. It has a Java api, which I think should do what you wanted.

Comment: thanks man ,,,, do you have some tutorial , or example to see that

Comment: Try this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323646/how-to-use-of-pay-pal-java-api